# I couldn't see overlapped material

Tags: materials

[image: Please watch this screen shot.]

When I move out that from the face molding, I can see it. How could I see it even it overlapped with others? I applied Flip Normals option to the outer face, is it affect this situation?

Comment: Perhaps you could add a screen shot to add clarity...

Comment: I added a screen shot. Please check it.